# Python turning a list of dataframes into one dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Using a bloomberg api to extract the data.... the output was a list of dataframes. Trying to merge them together. Here is what a snippet of the list looks like:

```
In[60]: df
Out[60]: 
[                               FDIDFDMO INDEX
 BN_SURVEY_AVERAGE                         0.9
 ECO_RELEASE_DT                     2022-03-15
 ECO_RELEASE_TIME                     08:30:00
 NAME               US PPI Final Demand MoM SA,
                                  INJCJC INDEX
 BN_SURVEY_AVERAGE                       215.3
 ECO_RELEASE_DT                     2022-03-10
 ECO_RELEASE_TIME                     08:30:00
 NAME             US Initial Jobless Claims SA]
```

Where "FDIDFDMO INDEX, INJCJC INDEX,... etc" are the column names. each dataframe is a dim of 4x1.

Comment: @BigBen Just edited.

Comment: Have you tried Pandas concat? https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html

Comment: @voidpointercast I tried that at first, wasn't working for some reason, maybe typo. But it worked now? I'll post my answer!!

Answer (score 2):

As @voidpointercast stated, pd.concat was correct.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.concat(df, axis = 1)
```